# when i want to reinstall the modules i get this error

Tags: 7

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_type_get_names() in /home/aukhma/public_html/modules/comment/comment.module on line 119
```

I got a  blank  page  when  I  would try to reinstall the node and the menu  modules.

The cause that pushed  me  to  reinstall those modules is that when I want to create a node for a new content type I can't find my new content type in the "add node" page.  So I did some research and found  a solution that said I need to rebuild the menu. I did that but got no result. I've also cleared the cache multiple times through the dash board.

Please, if any one can help find a solution I will be so happy, and thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type you create is stored in your database, no reason to do what you are trying to do.
Check your db tables for that types.

These are core modules that are never meant to be uninstalled, cause these kind of functions are used by other modules and core files without even a dependency on them cause they are considered ... core.

Better try with a fresh install.

Comment: OH !!! GOD but I have a old db could I import it ?

Comment: of course, through a desktop/web client or in your console (phpmyadmin/drush/mysql terminal)